# Starting an intent from an Android preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, preference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launch new activity from PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041292/launch-new-activity-from-preferenceactivity)

I have a Preference set up that I would like to start an intent that will display version and other information about the app. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to start an intent from a Preference. How would I do this? Please help. The preference is set up like this:

```
<Preference
    android:title="About"
    android:summary="About application"
    android:key="about"

    ></Preference>
```

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it, you have to do it custom. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4419551/642161).